# JavaScript: ¿Como puedo sumar los elementos numericos dentro de un json?

Tags: javascript, json, sql

Buen día a todos, mi consulta es la siguiente... Si tengo un objeto de tipo JSON en javascript, por ejemplo:

```
json = [{"Nombre":"Sutano","Edad":19},{"Nombre":"Fulano","Edad":20},{"Nombre":"Mengano","Edad":21}];
```

Y quiero sumar solamente los valores numericos dentro de cada elemento, en este caso, la edad, ¿Como podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 7):

En este caso te convendría usar [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce), aprovechando para verificar, antes de sumar, que el valor que hay en `Edad` es numérico. Si haces una suma inocente sin verificación, y por error hay un valor no numérico, el resultado total será `NaN`. O, si el número está entre comillas, se agregará a la suma total hasta el momento, produciendo resultados totalmente inverosímiles.

Este código evitaría eso.

La evaluación se hace aquí:
**`typeof value.Edad == "number" ? sum + value.Edad : sum`** mediante un operador ternario.

```js
var json = '[{"Nombre":"Sutano","Edad":19},{"Nombre":"Fulano","Edad":20},{"Nombre":"Mengano","Edad":21}]';

/*Convertimos la cadena a un array json*/
var arr = JSON.parse(json);

var totalAges = arr.reduce((sum, value) => (typeof value.Edad == "number" ? sum + value.Edad : sum), 0);
console.log(totalAges);
```

---

Probemos con un posible valor erróneo:

```js
var json = '[{"Nombre":"Sutano","Edad":19},{"Nombre":"Fulano","Edad":"Veinte"},{"Nombre":"Mengano","Edad":21},{"Nombre":"Sutana","Edad":"199999"}]';

/*Convertimos la cadena a un array json*/
var arr = JSON.parse(json);

var totalAges = arr.reduce((sum, value) => (typeof value.Edad == "number" ? sum + value.Edad : sum), 0);
console.log(totalAges);
```

---

#### Veamos un código sin verificación:

**Aquí bien:**

```js
var json = '[{"Nombre":"Sutano","Edad":19},{"Nombre":"Fulano","Edad":20}]';

/*Convertimos la cadena a un array json*/
var arr = JSON.parse(json);

var totalAges = arr.reduce((sum, value) => ( sum + value.Edad ), 0);
console.log(totalAges);
```

**Aquí ya no tan bien:**

```js
var json = '[{"Nombre":"Sutano","Edad":19},{"Nombre":"Fulano","Edad":"veinte"}]';

/*Convertimos la cadena a un array json*/
var arr = JSON.parse(json);

var totalAges = arr.reduce((sum, value) => ( sum + value.Edad ), 0);
console.log(totalAges);
```

**Aquí te pueden meter en la cárcel si se trata de sumar el total de una cuenta :) :**

```js
var json = '[{"Nombre":"Sutano","Edad":19},{"Nombre":"Fulano","Edad":"20"}]';

/*Convertimos la cadena a un array json*/
var arr = JSON.parse(json);

var totalAges = arr.reduce((sum, value) => ( sum + value.Edad ), 0);
console.log(totalAges);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes aca es un arreglo de objetos `json` en tu caso tienes que pasar todo el arreglo `javascript` a `json`, te dejo un ejemplo;

```js
//Arreglo javascript de objetos json
let json = [{"Nombre":"Sutano","Edad":19},{"Nombre":"Fulano","Edad":20},{"Nombre":"Mengano","Edad":21}];
//convirtiendo a json
json = JSON.stringify(json);
//Convirtiendo a objeto javascript
let data = JSON.parse(json);
var suma= 0;
//Recorriendo el objeto
for(let x in data){
  suma += data[x].Edad;//Ahora que es un objeto javascript, tiene propiedades
}

console.log('las edades suman: ' + suma);
```

Al final la variable `suma` contiene la suma de las edades, debes tomar en cuenta lo primero que mencione, que es que tienes un arreglo `javascript` de objetos `json` no un json puro por ello tuve que convertir a json lo que ya tenia la variable `json`

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, esta es mi primer respuesta en esta plataforma.

después de analizar la respuesta de Albert Hidalgo, se me hizo mucho rollo
asi que me puse a indagar y creo que esto hace lo mismo pero es mas simple:

```
var suma=0;
var json = [
        {"Nombre":"Sutano","Edad":19},
        {"Nombre":"Fulano","Edad":20},
        {"Nombre":"Mengano","Edad":21}
       ];

/*como la variable json ya esta en un formato valido, con el que tienes un arreglo 
como json, no es necesario convertirlo, con lo cual solo lo recorres y accedes al 
elemento que te interesa
*/
json.forEach(function(elemento, indice) {
    suma += elemento["Edad"];
});
console.log('las edades suman: ' + suma);
```

nota: la solución es correcta, me comentan cualquier observación con mi comentario, saludos