# como sumar objetos json por el id en javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, angular, typescript

como hago para sumar este objeto por su id y que la salida sea la siguiente

```
       [{
            "cont": 1,
            "id_pregunta": 39
        },
        {
            "cont": 1,
            "id_pregunta": 39
        },
        {
            "cont": 1,
            "id_pregunta": 38
        },
        {
            "cont": 1,
            "id_pregunta": 38
        }]
```

y la salida debe dar esto

```
[{
            "cont": 2,
            "id_pregunta": 39
        },
        {
            "cont": 2,
            "id_pregunta": 38
        }]
```

estaba intentando usar un reduce pero solo me suma todos los datos

```
let reduce = comprobar.reduce((acumulador, actual) => acumulador + actual.cont, 0);
console.log(reduce)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [JavaScript: ¿Como puedo sumar los elementos numericos dentro de un json?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212352/javascript-como-puedo-sumar-los-elementos-numericos-dentro-de-un-json)

Comment: Acá hay una respuesta que te puede ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/565065/301324

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Sumar valores de objetos en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/565031/sumar-valores-de-objetos-en-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías que filtrar a los objetos quienes tengan los valores repetidos de la clave **`id_pregunta`**, luego se entrará a una condición en el que su valor de **`cont`** irá incrementando para lo que se ha ido filtrando, dando como resultado final un nuevo arreglo de objetos con los valores sumados, sería algo así:

```js
const obj = [
  { cont: 1, id_pregunta: 39 },
  { cont: 1, id_pregunta: 39 },
  { cont: 1, id_pregunta: 38 },
  { cont: 1, id_pregunta: 38 }
];

const result = obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // De los objetos, filtramos a los valores que se repiten de la clave "id_pregunta".
  const obj = acc.find(o => o.id_pregunta === item.id_pregunta);
  // A lo que va filtrando, el valor de "cont" se sumará
  if (obj) {
    obj.cont += item.cont;
  } else {
    // De lo contrario, solo se hace push.
    acc.push(item);
  }
  // Retornamos el arreglo de objetos final.
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```